# submitting search value using Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am familiarizing myself with mvc and am trying to submit a text box value. As it is at the moment I am only getting a null value.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchProducts", "Home"))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchValue, new { @class = "input-medium search-query", @placeholder="Search" })

   <input type="submit" id="butSubmitSearchString" value="Submit" />


 }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchProducts(ViewModel model)
    {
        model = new ViewModel();
        string val = model.SearchValue;

        return View(model);
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public string SearchValue { get; set; }
```

How can I do this correctly so as to retrieve the textbox value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove this line:

```
model = new ViewModel();
```

The `ViewModel` is bound by the ASP.NET MVC framework. By removing that line you'll find the `val` is the actual value in `SearchValue`.

In other words, the `ViewModel` will already be instantiated and properties set when you get into the `HttpPost` action.

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating a new model instead of using the model you pass in parameters.
Just remove `model = new ViewModel();`